# Symfony 2.8 SyliusRecourceBundle routing criteria

Tags: php, symfony, sylius, symfony-2.8, symfony-routing

Right now I have a strange issue. Recently I started developing in Symfony 2.8. To learn in this framework I made an own project with an API. Everything works until i face a Route with a Criteria.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/index_resources.html#overriding-the-template-and-criteria) I only need to add "criteria" in the route file. But it isn't showing any difference. But when I add a "limit" too. Then it is working.

The Route file (A and B are fake):

```
api_A_B:
 path: /A/{id}/B
 methods: [GET]
 defaults:
   _controller: api.controller.B:indexAction
   _sylius:
     paginate: false
     #limit: 900 #WHY?
     criteria:
       A: $id
```

I read something about "filterable: true" but that was ages ago and it isn't in the documentation.

Query response with limit:

```
FROM 
  B t0 
WHERE 
  t0.A_id = ? 
LIMIT 
  900
```

Query response without limit:

```
FROM 
  B t0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the default Sylius resource resolver, it ignores criteria and sorting when your not paginating or `limit` is unset. To solve this, you should override the `sylius.resource_controller.resources_resolver.class` parameter and use the following implementation for the `getResources` method:

```
public function getResources(RequestConfiguration $requestConfiguration, RepositoryInterface $repository)
{
    if (null !== $repositoryMethod = $requestConfiguration->getRepositoryMethod()) {
        $callable = [$repository, $repositoryMethod];
        $resources = call_user_func_array($callable, $requestConfiguration->getRepositoryArguments());

        return $resources;
    }

    // this has changed!
    if (!$requestConfiguration->isPaginated() && !$requestConfiguration->isLimited()) {
        return $repository->findBy($requestConfiguration->getCriteria(), $requestConfiguration->getSorting(), $requestConfiguration->getLimit());
    }

    if (!$requestConfiguration->isPaginated()) {
        return $repository->findBy($requestConfiguration->getCriteria(), $requestConfiguration->getSorting(), $requestConfiguration->getLimit());
    }

    return $repository->createPaginator($requestConfiguration->getCriteria(), $requestConfiguration->getSorting());
}
```